# How to solve the problem with Firebase listener, which open everywhere?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I have some simple App, which have auth.
nearest code check if you already entered:

```
 func signingManager(){
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (auth, user) in
        guard let self = self else {return}
        if user != nil {
            self.showNextVC()
            print("You are already entered")
        }
    }
}
```

It's works when you first open the app and if you entered func "showNextVC" will open next VC.
In the same time i have login button with code :

```
    @IBAction func logInTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, email != "", password != "" else {
        displayWarningLabel(withText: "info is incorrect")
        return
    }
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { [weak self] (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self?.displayWarningLabel(withText: "error occured")
            return
        }
        if user != nil {
            self?.showNextVC()
            print("Congratulations, you have successfully logged in!")
        }
        self?.displayWarningLabel(withText: "no such user")
    }
)}
```

Now about the problem: if I click the "login" button, the "signingManager ()" method and it's "showNextVC" are triggered first, and only then the "logInTapped" method itself and again "showNextVC".
As a result, I have 2 VCs and two messages:
"You are already entered" and
"Congratulations, you have successfully logged in!"
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're listening for for auth state changes, you don't need to handle the `self?.showNextVC()` in the completion callback for `signIn(withEmail:, password:)`. That code should only be present in the callback for `addStateDidChangeListener`.

Alternatively, you can:

1. Use the `addStateDidChangeListener` to initially detect whether the user is signed-in already.
2. Inside the callback for the state change:

   1. Remove the listener by calling [`removeAuthStateDidChangeListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(im)removeAuthStateDidChangeListener:)
   2. Start the explicit sign-in flow, and call `signIn(withEmail:, password:)` like you're doing now.